# Unable to execute a simple "whoami" unix command using java program on the server

Tags: java, unix, process, aix

Im facing this strange issue of not being able to execute a simple "whoami" unix command on a AIX server. I have a webapplication that is deployed on an AIX server. Now I want to see under which WAS user my webapplication is currently running. So I added the below code:

```
    public String whoami() throws Exception {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("whoami");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        String output = "";

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            output += line;
        }
        in.close();
        p.destroy();
        return output;
    }
}
```

The above code is added in a jar file which is referred by a JSP. The JSP has to receive the output of the code above and it displays the WAS User name. But when i deploy the webapplication on the server and try to observe the output, im getting an error message like

> Error 500: access denied (java.io.FilePermission <> execute)

However, When I remove the above code and run my webapplication, everything runs fine. What wron am i doing here. Did I miss doing anything? Please help. This is the first time im working on UNIX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your web server has been configured with a Java security policy that prohibits executing external applications.

See http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html for information about Java Security Policies, and the documentation for your web server.

You will need to supply (or edit) a policy file to contain something like:

```
grant {
  permission java.io.FilePermission 
    "/usr/bin/whoami", "execute";
};
```

Comment: I guess this might be the actual issue. Will check this and see. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @SuryaChandra the error message you posted is completely consistent with a restricted security policy.

Comment: I see the following entries in the was.policy file

grant codeBase "file:${application}" {
};

grant codeBase "file:${jars}" {
};

grant codeBase "file:${connectorComponent}" {
};

grant codeBase "file:${webComponent}" {
};

grant codeBase "file:${ejbComponent}" {
};

Does the above imply that currently there are no access permissions for anything?

Comment: @SuryaChandra That seems to be the WebSphere default.  See http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftsec_waspolicyfile.html for info on which one of the five might be most appropriate to add the required permission.  Looks like either `file:${application}` or `file:${webComponent}` to me.

Comment: I think you were right. I will make the changes and see. Unfortunately, the server im working is down, I will update my observations soon

Comment: I updated the was.policy file to the following: grant {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/tmp/*", "read";
};
Currently, Im trying to read a file in a /tmp folder(earlier I was trying to execute whoami command which is not the actual task). But i still get the similar error. Did I do something wrong with the syntax when editing was.policy file as shown above? Pls let me know if you know anything on this

Comment: :Got it! I made the following modification to the was.policy file and it worked like a charm - grant codeBase "file:${application}" {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
};
Thanks a bunch for your support

Comment: @SuryaChandra great - glad to have pointed you in the right direction!  Not sure why your `/tmp/*` didn't work unless the file was actually in a sub-folder, in which case you should use `/tmp/-`.  Given access to `<<ALL FILES>>` may open up unwanted security holes.

Comment: @Alnitak- Yes, the file was actually in a sub folder inside /tmp, I didnt knew that I have to use '-' instead of '*'. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out. Yes, you were right in saying about acces to all files. I will modify that.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity
Have you considered to use:

```
user.name
```

System property in Java?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK whoami is a shell command and `Runtime#exec()` executes programs only.

you can try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh","-c","whoami"})` to call `sh` and let it execute `whoami`

another thing: do you need to destroy the process after reading?

Comment: Well, it is an actual program, it is located in /usr/bin. `Martijn-Pro:~ martijncourteaux$ which whoami` returns `/usr/bin/whoami`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ProcessBuilder` class instead of `getRuntime().exec("whoami")`.

Here is sample code

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DoProcessBuilder {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        if (args.length <= 0) {
            System.err.println("Need command to run");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        System.out.printf("Output of running &#37;s is:", Arrays.toString(args));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a `ProcessBuilder` should be restricted to the same security policies as `Runtime.exec`